# Libreoffice is losing the title of my doc files

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, libreoffice

I am using Libreoffice Writer 3.6.2.2 with Ubuntu 12.10 amd64, nothing special, just the standard libreoffice that comes from the standard download of 12.10 amd64 from ubuntu.com. Each time I open a doc file (MS WORD) it loses the title and it displays only "Untitled 1" in the title and as a result when I hit the save button it ask me for a name and even when I chose the doc file format it still does not display the file in the list of the dialog so I can choose it and it forces me to retype the whole name.

It seems to even lose the location of the file as well, so the save dialog does not send me to the folder the file is located.

Another weird behavior is that even though libreoffice opens its icon on the left bar does not show the white arrow to indicate the programm is running as it does with all the other opened programms.

Is this a known problem and if yes is there a fix ? I tried to google it but I have not found anyone else reporting this.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the file did not have the ".doc" extension which cause the "untitled" problem. Still seems like a bug to me , but fortunately its a minor one .